Scalling image saved in D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE pResource
I am using DuplicateOutput to capture the screen. AcquireNextFrame gives me the captured image.
In the end i map it using:
hr = mComPtrlImmediateContext->Map(mComPtrlDestImage, subresource,
 D3D11_MAP_READ_WRITE, 0, &moResource);//moResource is D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE type.

I now want to scale the image. I do not want to use shaders (too complex) so I am using DXVAHD (VideoProcessBltHD) to scale it in GPU since moResource in in GPU.
Issue is that moResource is D3D11 and DXVAHD uses IDirect3DSurface9.
So to load the D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE to DXVAHD IDirect3DSurface9 I use this:
HRESULT DXVAHDImageResizer::LoadResourceToSurface(D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE* pResource)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    D3DLOCKED_RECT lr = { 0 };
    bool bNeedToUnlock = false;;
    try
    {
        hr = mpSurface->LockRect(&lr, NULL, D3DLOCK_NOSYSLOCK);
        if (FAILED(hr)) { goto done; }
        bNeedToUnlock = true;
        UINT iDestRowPitch = lr.Pitch;
        UINT iSourceRowPitch = pResource->RowPitch;

        BYTE* sptr = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(pResource->pData);
        BYTE* dptr = (byte*)lr.pBits;
        int iPitchToCopy = min(iDestRowPitch, iSourceRowPitch);
        for (int h = 0; h < moInputVideoInfoHeader.bmiHeader.biHeight; ++h)
        {
            memcpy(dptr, sptr, iPitchToCopy);
            dptr += iDestRowPitch;
            sptr += iSourceRowPitch;
        }
    }
    catch (...) { DEBUG_BREAK_MY }
done:
    if (bNeedToUnlock) mpSurface->UnlockRect();
     
    return hr;
}

But as you can see, this goes to CPU to copy.

Is there a way to load the D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE to IDirect3DSurface9  without going to CPU?
Or do you have another way to scale the image stored in D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE using GPU without using shaders?

Someone asked in comment why i map it in the first place to CPU. The only reason is that this is the only way i found to feed DXVAHD  with the captured data.

12/7/24 Update for @Simon Mourier Question
This is what I have:
CComPtrCustom<ID3D11Texture2D> mComPtrlGDIImage;
desc.Width = SourceWidth;
desc.Height = SourceHeight;
desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
desc.ArraySize = 1;
desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_FLAG::D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET;
desc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_GDI_COMPATIBLE;
desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
desc.MipLevels = 1;
desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
hr = mlDevice->CreateTexture2D(&desc, NULL, &mComPtrlGDIImage);
    
hr = mComPtrlDeskDupl->AcquireNextFrame(0, &lFrameInfo, &lDesktopResource);
hr = lDesktopResource->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&lAcquiredDesktopImage));
mComPtrlImmediateContext->CopySubresourceRegion(mComPtrlGDIImage,
 0, 0, 0, 0, lAcquiredDesktopImage, 0, &box);

Now mComPtrlGDIImage contains the GPU image.
Now I want to scale it to lets say 1000X1700. How to do that?

AFAIK you map a texture to gain CPU access. If you want to avoid CPU processing, why to you map it in the first place?

You can use Direct2D to resize bitmaps, this will work in GPU and you don't need a dependency on legacy DXVAHD/DirectX9

@Mehrzad Chehraz The only reason is that this is the only way i found to feed DXVAHD with the captured data.

@Martin121233 You should keep the texture in GPU to get the best performance and as Simon said, you should either use Direct2D, Shader or use a library which uses one of those.

@Simon Mourier
do you have any idea how to scale image using Direct2D. I tried for hours with SetTransform and then DrawImage but seems DrawImage does nothing. i could not find example. I have the image in GPU in ID3D11Texture2D. I have its ID2D1DeviceContext but how do i scale it? thanks!

If mComPtrlDestImage is a the input ID3D11Resource that you got from AcquireNextFrame, what scaled output type do you expect exactly?

I updated the  original question with more info, it starts with "12/7/24 Update for @Simon Mourier Question" As you can see I have the GPU image in mComPtrlGDIImage (DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM) Dimension are same as source screen Dimension. Now i want to Scale it lets say to 1000X1700. Scale should be made as u suggested in GPU using Direct2D (I prefer not Shader). So how I proceed from here? I tried to load it to ID2D1Bitmap1 and use DrawImage with D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Scale but seems DrawImage do nothing. So I am not sure this is the way. Thanks!!

what the expected output type? a D3D11 texture? or what are you going to do with it after scale

After the scale i need to get it out into cpu buffer to send it to h264 encoder. what i do is Capture screen using DuplicateOutput. Have the captured image in mComPtrlGDIImage, then i need to resize the image to lets say 1000X1700. This all done in GPU. then i need to send it to H264 encoder but my H264 Encoder does not know to work with GPU so i need to get it out to CPU buffer, convert it to I420 and send it to h264Encoder.
So currently the screen capturing is done in GPU and i want the resize/scaling to be done there is GPU as well - and here i ask your help with the scaling.

Of, so it's probably more natural to use Media Foundation Video Processor MFT instead which is made for this and can output to I420 at the same time. And this supports GPU-accelerated processing, with D3D11 see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/video-processor-mft there's a sample on how to use it https://github.com/smourier/VCamSample/blob/main/VCamSampleSource/FrameGenerator.cpp#L78 to resize at the same time pass MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE to input & output  media types

Thanks Simon. I managed to get it working with D2D (with d2dContext->DrawImage(scaleEffect)) and I think MFT will not give better results and this is more simple and also as MFT does on GPU.

one thing i have issue with is: My Resize func:
CComPtrCustom d2dBitmapGPU;
d2dContext->CreateBitmapFromDxgiSurface(dxgiSurfaceGPU, &bitmapPropsGPU, &d2dBitmapGPU);
d2dBitmapGPU2->CopyFromBitmap(nullptr, d2dBitmapGPU, nullptr);
d2dContext->BeginDraw();
d2dContext->DrawImage(scaleEffect);
hr = d2dContext->EndDraw();
The source image is in dxgiSurfaceGPU and as you can see to copy it to bitmapPropsGPU i use CreateBitmapFromDxgiSurface which create the bitmap mem in GPU and copy.Is there way just to copy (I will create the bitmap before) without reallocate mem in GPU

The DXGI surface you get from AcquireNextFrame is not always the same so you need to  call CreateBitmapFromDxgiSurface from it, however you can keep the rest as is (D2D device, device context, bitmaps, etc.) Not sure why you need to copy from d2dBitmapGPU you should be able to draw it directly. Share a reproducing project if you need more help

You ask why i do  scaleEffect->SetInput(0, d2dBitmapGPU2); and not  scaleEffect->SetInput(0, d2dBitmapGPU); i.e why i have d2dBitmapGPU2 . well I copy to d2dBitmapGPU2 since seems that the bitmap need to have D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_NONE for  SetInput to work and if i give it D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_NONE in CreateBitmapFromDxgiSurface then CreateBitmapFromDxgiSurface  will fail. So d2dBitmapGPU is created in CreateBitmapFromDxgiSurface  with D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_TARGET | D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_CANNOT_DRAW while SetInput gets d2dBitmapGPU2 with D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_NONE. Not sure why. I am new in this :) :)
